# Displaying info contained in a tablet it "belongs to" and putting it in a view loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise, database-relations

I've searched for this answer and can't find it anywhere in stack overflow.

Here's my problem.

A gurgle belongs to user.
A user has many gurgles

I want to be able to display in a loop, the data from another table that it has a active record relation to.

When I display gurgles own index.html.erb in a loop retrieving only its own table info, it works fine.

But when I try to retrieve the info of the user of which that gurgle belongs to, it throws an error.

There is something here I am just not getting and I am hoping someone can help.
I get a lot of different errors depending how I change it but as it stands this is the error Im getting now...

**It currently doesn't like @user.email...**

**NoMethodError in Gurgles # index
undefined method `email' for # User::ActiveRecord_Relation
Extracted source (around line #17):**

```
      <tr>
        <td><p><%= image_tag("zombie_profile.png", width: '100px') %><%= gurgle.status %></p></td>
        <td><p><%= @user.email %></p></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my code:

My gurgle model file...

```
class Gurgle < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: "user_id"


end
```

My model for user (using devise engine here)...

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :gurgles
  has_one :profile

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

My gurgle controller code...

```
class GurglesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_gurgle, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  layout 'gurgle'

  # GET /gurgles
  # GET /gurgles.json
  def index
    @gurgle = Gurgle.all


    @user = User.all

  end

  # GET /gurgles/1
  # GET /gurgles/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /gurgles/new
  def new
    @gurgle = Gurgle.new
  end

  # GET /gurgles/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /gurgles
  # POST /gurgles.json
  def create


    @user = User.find(current_user)
    @gurgle = @user.gurgles.new(gurgle_params)


    respond_to do |format|
      if @gurgle.save
        format.html { redirect_to @gurgle, notice: 'Gurgle was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @gurgle }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @gurgle.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /gurgles/1
  # PATCH/PUT /gurgles/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @gurgle.update(gurgle_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @gurgle, notice: 'Gurgle was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @gurgle }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @gurgle.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /gurgles/1
  # DELETE /gurgles/1.json
  def destroy
    @gurgle.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to gurgles_url, notice: 'Gurgle was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_gurgle
      @gurgle = Gurgle.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def gurgle_params
      params.require(:gurgle).permit(:status, :user_id)
    end
end
```

My gurgle index.html.erb code....

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<br />
<hr>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @gurgle.each do |gurgle| %>
      <tr>
        <td><p><%= image_tag("zombie_profile.png", width: '100px') %><%= gurgle.status %></p></td>
        <td><p><%= @user.email %></p></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<br />

<p><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_gurgle_path(gurgle), class: "gurgle-links" %> | <%= link_to 'Delete', gurgle, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "gurgle-links" %></p>

<br />
<hr>

    <% end %>


<br />
<br />

<%= button_to 'New Gurgle', new_gurgle_path, class: "btn btn-primary", method: :get %>
```

and finally the schema on how my tables are set up in the database....

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170101132806) do

  create_table "gurgles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "status"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_gurgles_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.text     "about"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_profiles_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

What am I doing wrong or missing here....

Comment: you can access `user` object based on `gurgles` object

Comment: Where and how do i do that?

Comment: Doesn't work. Now I get undefined method `user' when I use that in index.html.erb

Comment: can you check `Gurgle.first.user` in console?

Comment: I get the following  Gurgle Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "gurgles".* FROM "gurgles" ORDER BY "gurgles"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => nil  ....... wouldn't no method suggest its not lack of a record? or am I reading the meaning of no method error wrongly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132604/discussion-between-uzaif-and-kalcoder).

Comment: @uzaif `@gurgle.user.email` doesn't make sense. @gurgle is all gurgles. You need to iterate through @gurgles and then call each one's user.

Comment: yes its typo and i resolved that one thanks for pointing me.

Comment: Had a detailed chat with @uzaif and it turns out some records had no entry under the foreign key, so every time it was going to refer to the associated record, it didn't know where to go. The solution was to either put in conditional code to say.... <td><p><%= gurgle.user.email unless gurgle.user.nil? %></p></td> or delete the records not containing foreign key IDs all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  def index
    @gurgle = Gurgle.all
  end
```

in index.html.erb try to update below code

```
<td><p><%= gurgle.user.email %></p></td>
```

with gurgle object you can access user email because you have association but sometimes it cause an error because your `gurgle` data does not contain user_id  so it will throw an error

remove @user from index action

Comment: Yup. Turns out I didn't have foreign ID entries for some of the records, so it didn't know where to point to grab the associated data. Such a rookie mistake but glad its fixed. Thanks @uzaif for your time!

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
<% @gurgle.each do |gurgle| %>
      <tr>
        <td><p><%= image_tag("zombie_profile.png", width: '100px') %><%= gurgle.status %></p></td>
        <td><p><%= gurgle.user.email rescue nil %></p></td>
      </tr>
<% end %>
```